# Subset multiple columns by .N in large data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large `data.table` that contains millions of rows and 30 columns. The columns contain a varying number of categorical features. I would like to remove any features that occur less than a certain proportion.

Here is an example:

```
dt <- data.table(id=1:18,col1=c(rep("a",5), rep("b",10), rep("c",3)), col2=c(rep("d",12),rep("e",5),"f"))
dt
    id col1 col2
 1:  1    a    d
 2:  2    a    d
 3:  3    a    d
 4:  4    a    d
 5:  5    a    d
 6:  6    b    d
 7:  7    b    d
 8:  8    b    d
 9:  9    b    d
10: 10    b    d
11: 11    b    d
12: 12    b    d
13: 13    b    e
14: 14    b    e
15: 15    b    e
16: 16    c    e
17: 17    c    e
18: 18    c    f
```

For example, I only want to keep features that occur more than a proportion of 0.5 per column:

```
> dt[,.N,by=col1][N/sum(N)>0.5]
   col1  N
1:    b 10
```

and

```
> dt[,.N,by=col2][N/sum(N)>0.5]
   col2  N
1:    d 12
```

The way I approached this is to loop over the columns and use `%in%`

```
for (i in 1:2) dt[, paste0('newcol',i) :=lapply(dt[[paste0('col',i)]],
 function(y) ifelse(y %in% dt[,.N,by=dt[[paste0('col',i)]]][N/sum(N)>0.5][[1]],y,"") )]
```

and then I create a new column that holds the merged values `dt[, merge := paste(newcol1,newcol2), by=id]`
which gets me my desired output in column **merge**:

```
> dt
    id col1 col2 newcol1 newcol2 merge
 1:  1    a    d               d     d
 2:  2    a    d               d     d
 3:  3    a    d               d     d
 4:  4    a    d               d     d
 5:  5    a    d               d     d
 6:  6    b    d       b       d   b d
 7:  7    b    d       b       d   b d
 8:  8    b    d       b       d   b d
 9:  9    b    d       b       d   b d
10: 10    b    d       b       d   b d
11: 11    b    d       b       d   b d
12: 12    b    d       b       d   b d
13: 13    b    e       b            b 
14: 14    b    e       b            b 
15: 15    b    e       b            b 
16: 16    c    e                      
17: 17    c    e                      
18: 18    c    f
```

The trouble is that this is really **slow** on a large data set. I suspect that I am not approaching this in "data.table-y" way. I also have to be very careful about not copying the original dataset because it barely fits into my RAM, which is why `data.table` is so appealing in the first place. I don't care however if there any intermediate steps as long as the process is quicker.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1    Rcpp_0.11.2   reshape2_1.4  stringr_0.6.2 tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: I am having a little trouble understanding what you want.  Do you want the rows with (b and d) or (b and/or d)?

Comment: Do you've to generate `newcols` or are you interested only in the final column `merge`?

Comment: It isn't clear if you are interested in the new columns you are generating or the col1 and col2 values that match certain criteria.

Comment: @Arun Indeed `newcols` intermediate columns are not needed. It was just my attempt to highlight my thinking process

Comment: Great, how about `cols`? Can we overwrite them? Or do you need it for later?

Comment: @mgriebe I basically want the `merge` column. I just highlighted the intermediate steps and columns as I approached the problem. I am pretty sure that with `:=` in `data.table` new columns are added by reference, so not copied

Comment: @Arun Actually, don't need the original `cols` either. Would that make a difference to your approach?

Comment: @MichaelWhitaker, of course! Hold on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully I've gotten it right this time. Too much time wasted on wrong answers!

```
cols = paste("col", 1:2, sep="")
rows = nrow(dt)
for (i in seq_along(cols)) {
    dt[, (cols[i]) := if (.N/rows <= .5) "", by=c(cols[i])]
}
dt[, merge := do.call(paste, c(as.list(dt)[-1L], sep= " "))]
```

---

Here's a benchmark on 1e6 * 30 columns:

```
set.seed(1L)
dt = setDT(lapply(1:30, function(x) sample(letters[1:4], 1e6, TRUE)))
system.time({
    cols = paste("V", 1:30, sep="")
    rows = nrow(dt)
    for (i in seq_along(cols)) {
        dt[, (cols[i]) := if (.N/rows <= .5) "", by=c(cols[i])]
    }
    dt[, merge := do.call(paste, c(as.list(dt)[-1L], sep= " "))]
})
#  user  system elapsed 
# 4.880   0.086   5.095
```

I'll let you pickup any further optimisations possible. Good luck!

Comment: Making a new column for almost every column in the data set is tantamount to copying the data set.

Comment: @mgriebe, right. I dint get an answer for the comment. So went ahead and added another... Not sure if it's fast though.

Comment: @Arun. Thanks so much! I will be able to run this on my data set tomorrow

Comment: @mgriebe: yes, but that can trivially be parallelized and hence is scalable, unlike `%in%` operator, which is `O(N)`

Comment: Thanks @Arun. This works flawlessly on my 6m+ dataset.  `user  system elapsed 38.337   4.312  42.640 `    Also very much appreciate learning about pasting multiple columns programmatically via `do.call(paste...`